# Format a string, clear specific characters in a string?

Tags: c#

```
string FormatString(string text)
{

// example of a string text recieved...
// /test/test1/test2/important-text-here-random

// example a-top => return should be...
// Important Text Here Random

// please and ty

// a quirk I have is that the text that needs to be formatted is always after that last / incase I do not know how to calculate a random amount of / in a string.

}
```

The question is inside the function itself.

Please help? I need the most efficient way to do so...

example of text recieved would be: /test/test1/test2/important-text-here-random

I need it formatted to: Important Text Here Random

Thank you.

Comment: I am not able to get your question. can you please try to re-phrase it?

Comment: If this is a file path, try using `var afterSlash = Path.GetFileName(text);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I understand from your question. This may work for you.

```
string FormatString(string text)
{
   // Get the last string and replace the "-" to space.
   string output = text.split('/').Last().Replace("-"," ");

   // convert it into title case
   output  = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(output); 
   return output;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LastIndexOf` method here.

```
string FormatString(string text)
{    
  return text.Remove(0,text.LastIndexOf("/")+1);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split and get the last value

```
string FormatString(string text)
{
string [] allvalues=text.Split('/');
return (allvalues[allvalues.Length - 1]).Replace("-"," ");
}
```